# Drawing a VSIS image bitmap on a non-visible area

Tags: image, windows-runtime, directx, winrt-xaml

I am trying to create a flipview based windowsRT application where each item of the flipview(a page in my app's terminology) is a [VSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.virtualsurfaceimagesource.aspx) backed image. As per the design of VSIS, whenever any image comes into the visible area, the updatesneeded function of VSIS gets called and draws the bitmap for me.

As an enhancement, I want to cache the image/bitmap of the next page which will be displayed if the user clicks on the next button. To achieve that, I call the invalidate function of the corresponding VSIS in a different thread hoping that this would render the bitmap in background(by a call to UpdatesNeeded) and by the time user clicks the next button, the image would already be ready to be displayed.

But it seems that the invalidate function does not call the updatesneeded callback when the VSIS is not in the visible area and hence my caching design is failing. Is there a way/workaround for the same? I know the dimensions of the page/image beforehand so getting the update rects for vsis is not a problem. Moreover, my updatesneeded function will just return if the bitmap is already rendered taking care that when the image comes in the visible area and updatesneeded is called, VSIS would not need to redraw the whole image again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Actually it was wrong on my side to assume that the `UpdatesNeeded` function would get called even when my image is not in the visible region. So instead, I have implemented my own function `PreCacheImage`. When called, this function creates an `ID2D1Bitmap` of the image and stores it. And when the `UpdatesNeeded` function gets called(when image becomes visible), I check whether my Bitmap is valid, and if it is, I just blit it onto the screen.